# Postgresql generate series with interval '15 minutes' longer than 29092 items

Tags: postgresql

Sut:

```
create table meter.materialized_quarters
(
    id int4 not null generated by default as identity,
    tm timestamp without time zone
    ,constraint pk_materialized_quarters primary key (id)
    --,constraint uq_materialized_quarters unique (tm) 
);
```

Then setup data:

```
insert into meter.materialized_quarters (tm) 
select GENERATE_SERIES ('1999-01-01', '2030-10-30', interval '15 minute');
```

And check data:

```
    select count(*),tm 
    from meter.materialized_quarters 
    group by tm  
    having count(*)> 1
```

Some results:

```
count|tm                     |
-----+-----------------------+
    2|1999-10-31 02:00:00.000|
    2|1999-10-31 02:15:00.000|
    2|1999-10-31 02:30:00.000|
    2|1999-10-31 02:45:00.000|
    2|2000-10-29 02:00:00.000|
    2|2000-10-29 02:15:00.000|
    2|2000-10-29 02:30:00.000|
    2|2000-10-29 02:45:00.000|
    2|2001-10-28 02:00:00.000|
    2|2001-10-28 02:15:00.000|
    2|2001-10-28 02:30:00.000|

....
```

Details:

```
select * from meter.materialized_quarters where tm = '1999-10-31 01:45:00';
```

Result:

```
id   |tm                     |
-----+-----------------------+
29092|1999-10-31 01:45:00.000|
```

As I see, 29092 is maximum series of nonduplicated data generated by: GENERATE_SERIES with 15 minutes interval.
How to fill table (meter.materialized_quarters) from 1999 to 2030?

One solution is:

insert into meter.materialized_quarters (tm)
select GENERATE_SERIES ('1999-01-01', '1999-10-31 01:45:00', interval '15 minute');

then:

insert into meter.materialized_quarters (tm)
select GENERATE_SERIES ('1999-10-31 02:00:00.000', '2000-10-29 00:00:00.000', interval '15 minute');

and again, and again.

Or

```
with bad as (
    select count(*),tm
    from meter.materialized_quarters 
    group by tm  
    having count(*)> 1
) 
, ids as (
    select mq1.id, mq2.id as iddel
    from meter.materialized_quarters mq1 inner join bad on bad.tm = mq1.tm inner join meter.materialized_quarters mq2 on bad.tm = mq2.tm 
    where mq1.id<mq2.id
)
delete from meter.materialized_quarters
where id in (select iddel from ids);
```

Is there more 'elegant' way?

EDIT.
I see the problem.
xxxx-10-29 02:00:00 - summer time become winter time.

select GENERATE_SERIES ('1999-10-31 01:45:00', '1999-10-31 02:00:00', interval '15 minute');

Comment: I don't understand your question. You are checking a row from 1999, obviously that will not include a value from 2030. Your code **will** insert rows until 2030 which you can easily verify with `select max(tm) from materialized_quarters`  https://dbfiddle.uk/KugUodV7

Comment: If I remove comment from unique constraint, eg: uq_materialized_quarters

then executing:
insert into meter.materialized_quarters (tm) 
select GENERATE_SERIES ('1999-01-01', '2030-10-30', interval '15 minute');

stops with error:

SQL Error [23505]: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_materialized_quarters"
  Detail: Key (tm)=(1999-10-31 02:00:00) already exists.

First select query from oryginal question shows the problem: duplicated records.
It means, that insert ... generate_series ... from 199 to 2030 generate duplicated records around 1999-10-31 02:00:00

Comment: Another check:

with series as (select tm from GENERATE_SERIES ('1999-01-01', '1999-10-31 01:45:00', interval '15 minute') as tm)
select count(*) from series; -- 29092

with series as (select tm from GENERATE_SERIES ('1999-01-01', '1999-10-31 02:00:00', interval '15 minute') as tm)
select count(*) from series; -- 29097

They differ by 15 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the conversion from `timestamp WITH time zone` which is returned by `generate_series()` and your column which is defined as `timestamp WITHOUT time zone`.

`1999-10-31` is the day where daylight savings time changes (at least in some countries)

If you change your column to `timestamp WITH time zone` your code works without any modification.

[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/_jWYmx0S)

---

If you want to stick with `timestamp WITHOUT timestamp` you need to convert the value returned by `generate_series()`

```
insert into materialized_quarters (tm) 
select g.tm at time zone 'UTC' --<< change to the time zone you need
from GENERATE_SERIES ('1999-01-01', '2030-10-30', interval '15 minute') as g(tm)
```

[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/9bEo5o06)